# How to dynamically change option in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two different questions here:

Heres the code I want to modify a bit.

```
 <select
   :name="'pipeline_status' + opportunityId"
   :id="'pipeline_status' + opportunityId"
   class="form-control"
   v-model="pipelineStatus"
   @change="setTransitionState"
   > 
     <option
     v-for="state in pipelineStatusOptions"
     :key="state.id"
     :value="state.id"
     >{{state.primary_state}}
     </option>
  </select>

methods: {
   setTransitionState(){
      this.inTransition = true; (This triggers the modals)
   }

}

'pipelineStatus' in the v-model equals out to be the id of each selected option
```

I was wondering if its possible to change {{state.primary_state}} dynamically? Also my second question, for some reason when I select certain options, some options trigger a new modal, which is the expected behavior, but I after the user is done with the modal (which is usually a form), the dropdown option resets to its previous state, and doesn't display the one that triggers the modal unless I refresh the page. Is there a possible way to fix this? Maybe some sort of re-rendering? Because the option that triggers the modal should be displaying after the form modal is complete, and not only after a reload. The other options that don't trigger something usually just stick there. Thoughts?

Comment: since you bind the model with "pipelineStatus" , if you change the value of "pipelineStatus" with in any method it will reflect in the dropdown.

Comment: it seems some of you methods or element is changing the value of "pipelineStatus". double check the forms fields in the modal have binded with same "pipelineStatus" variable